# Convert Java Byte Array to a UTF-8 Python String

Tags: java, python, json, arrays

I'm pulling JSON data through a REST API using Requests in Python.  Unfortunately, one of the fields contains all sorts of unescaped and control characters that breaks the JSON.

I don't control the data, but I can request it undecoded as a string that the application stores as a Java byte array.

For example: [B@1cf3bd82

The question is how do I decode the string back into the original UTF-8 text as I'm working through the JSON?  All of the examples I've found seem to work with a byte object, not a encoded string.

Thoughts?

Comment: This looks like the data given to you is incorrect.  This looks like it is simply doing a toString on a byte array.  This is a reference to the byte array, not its contents.

Answer (score 1):

You're currently printing out the result of calling `toString()` on the `byte[]`. That's never a good idea - arrays don't override `toString()`.

You should use the `new String(byte[], Charset)` constructor:

```
String text = new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

It's not entirely clear to me from the question where what is happening in terms of the data, but basically you need to modify the *Java* code - any Python code is probably irrelevant here.

Comment: as I see it, the OP is the consumer of the REST API call, not the provider.  Unless he can change the java code he is stuffed.

Comment: @ScaryWombat: It's possible that's the case - I didn't find the question easy to follow. But wherever the Java code is and whoever owns it, that's the code that needs to be changed.